# How to return the velocity of a bone at a certain frame?

Tags: python, bones

How would I return the velocity of a certain bone at each frame during my animation? And ideally I'd want to be able to output all of these velocity values as metadata in a text file or the console to see. I'm not exactly the best Python coder let alone coding for Blender so I'd greatly appreciate if someone could show me how to do this.

I think this would be done by taking the time between two keyframes divided by the position of the bone at the previous keyframe subtracted from the current keyframe like so: (time between two frames)/(current frame - previous frame)

But I need the velocity at every single frame in the animation, not at every keyframe. Much appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the bone are you talking about. Not all of the bone can be at same velocity. Please can you provide a clearer picture.

Comment: The location of the bone in pose mode, let's say I have a walking animation with IK legs. If I want to find the velocity of the IK controller at a certain frame, how should I do that?